# Split array column and result into extra Colums

Tags: powershell

I have a table (CSV) which shows all the users that have ever logged on to a bunch of computers. Users can have 2 accounts, one username starts with "a" the other with "b", like a100 and b100 (the user behind is the same person).

Now I need to get the computers that have more then 2 accounts logged on which do not belong the same users. So A64 and B64 are not reported as separate users.

Here is the base list I have:

```
PC1,A64,B52,B64,A41
PC2,A51,B42,B51,A23
PC3,A42,B51
PC4,A5,B5
PC5,A1,B1,A14,A6
```

My plan was to split the "User"-column into more columns, so the table would look like this:

```
Computername,user1,user2,user3,user4,UserX
```

After this was done, I could iterate through the table and remove the leading letter in the Username, then I would try to get rid of doubles.

Do you think that makes sense?

Now I got stuck in the first task already. I know how to iterate though the second Column but how do I managed to get the result into another array so the output would be like:

```
Computername,user1,user2,user3,user4,UserX
```

Can you help me split?

```
$UserComputers = import-csv -Delimiter ";" "input.csv" -Header 
'Computername','user1','user2','user3','user4'


$UserComputers | Select-Object *,
    @{n='User1';e={$_.User1.Split(',')[0]}},
    @{n='User2';e={$_.User1.Split(',')[1]}}
```

I get the error: Select-Object : The property cannot be processed because the property "User1" already exists.

Answer (score 2):

It is useful to make "user" an array.

```
Get-Content "input.csv" | foreach {
    $name, $users = $_.Split(",")
    [pscustomobject]@{ Name = $name; Users = $users }
} | Where-Object { ($_.Users.Substring(1) | Select-Object -Unique).Count -gt 2 }
```

The output is below.

```
Name Users               
---- -----               
PC1  {A64, B52, B64, A41}
PC2  {A51, B42, B51, A23}
PC3  {A42, B51}          
PC5  {A1, B1, A14, A6}
```

Comment: Should be `.Count -gt 2 }` cite `more than 2 (unique) accounts` (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Input File (input.csv)

```
PC1,A64,B52,B64,A41
PC2,A51,B42,B51,A23
PC3,A42,B51
PC4,A5,B5
PC5,A1,B1,A14,A6
```

Powershell Script

```
Get-Content -Path .\input.csv | 
Select-Object @{ Name = "Computer"; Expression = { $_.Split(',')[0] } }, 
              @{ Name="Users"; Expression = { $_.Split(',')[1..($_.Split(',').Length-1)] | 
Foreach-Object { $_.Substring(1) } | Select-Object -Unique } } | 
Where-Object { $_.Users.Count -gt 2 }
```

Result:

```
Computer      Users
------------- -----
PC1      {64, 52, 41}
PC2      {51, 42, 23}
PC5      {1, 14, 6}
```

P.S. Bonus: If you want to see more than 4 elements of the array on the screen change the variable 
    `$FormatEnumerationLimit = 20`
[Explanation of the variable meaning](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/change-a-powershell-preference-variable-to-reveal-hidden-data/)

Comment: The requirement was `more then 2 (unique) accounts` so it should be `Where-Object { $_.Users.Count -gt 2 }` Otherwise +1

Answer (score 0):

If your file is like your base list, you can do the following to build a new file with all the columns you need:

```
$maxColCount = 0
$data = get-content input.csv
foreach ($line in $data) {
   $MaxColCount = [math]::Max($maxcolcount,($line -split ",").count)
}

$headers = @("ComputerName")
$MaxUserCount = $MaxColCount - 1
Foreach ($c in (1..$MaxUserCount)) {
   $Headers += "User$c"
}
$Headers = $Headers -join ","

$Headers,$data | Set-Content "output.csv"
```

The code above assumes `input.csv` has the following format and each column after the first is a user:

```
PC1,A64,B52,B64,A41
PC2,A51,B42,B51,A23
PC3,A42,B51
PC4,A5,B5
PC5,A1,B1,A14,A6
```